# How to use the Same Calendar Overlay(s) across 12 of the same Calendar web part on 1 page

Tags: 2013, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, overlay, js

This question references this post: [Need to Display an Annual View Using Multiple Calendar Webparts on the Same Webpage](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233405/need-to-display-an-annual-view-using-multiple-calendar-webparts-on-the-same-webp)

So we were able to get the page set up with 12 of the same web part connected to the same calendar to present an annual view. I can successfully use css to resize the calendar and the cells within. I can apply calendar overlays using the tool... however, the view of the calendar overlay only shows on the last month of December... it will not populate data shown in the other web parts.

Is there something that will allow me to force the overlay to apply to all of the "cells" on the page?

Thanks for looking! Please let me know if you need screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, each list view webpart works with its own copy of list view. So if you have created overlay directly in calendar list, you will need to edit each webpart and select the view with overlay.

Comment: I will review that in the morning, but it appeared earlier that all the webparts were taking me to the same overlay setup screen. Will advise.

Comment: Instead of creating or modifying view from the webpart, try creating a new view for your calendar(from all site content) with desired overlay and set that new view in your web parts. It worked for me, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am new enough to SP13 that I am unsure how to do that... However, your answer of each WP having its own listing for overlays is correct. I did have to enter them, then change the view of the WP from default to Calendar under Edit Web Part to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)